# How can you change the font color using Timer control

Tags: delphi

I am trying to change `Label01 Font Color` using `Timer04`. My requirement is to increase the decimal value of font color starting from **0** to **16777215**. When the font colour will reach **16777215** then the same will be decreased to **0** again. It will be a continuous loop. If the proportions of increment and decrement for the basic three colors (**RGB*) are the same then only it will be from Black to White and White to Black.
So I defined the following codes:

```
procedure TMainForm.Timer04Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  RedColor, GreenColor, BlueColor: integer;
begin
  RedColor := 1;
  GreenColor := 2;
  BlueColor := 3;
  if (RedColor >= 1) and (RedColor <= 255) then RedColor := RedColor + 5;
  if (GreenColor >= 1) and (RedColor <= 255) then GreenColor := GreenColor + 5;
  if (BlueColor >= 1) and (BlueColor <= 255) then BlueColor := BlueColor + 5;
  Label01.Font.Color := RedColor + GreenColor + BlueColor;
end;
..
..
..
..
..
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer04.Enabled := true;
end;
```

But it is not happening so. Only Black color is vissible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But take some external place to hold your value outside the procedure - because local variables do not exist (and the value in them is lost) after procedure exit (otherwise recursion and multithreading would be impossible)

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  ....
  private 
    Luminosity: byte;
    Direction:  shortint; 
  end;

// Those variables exist in the form itself, outside of 
//   the procedure, thus can be used to hold the values you need.

procedure TMainForm.Timer04Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label01.Font.Color := RGB(Luminosity, Luminosity, Luminosity);

  if ((Luminosity =   0) and (Direction < 0)) or 
     ((Luminosity = 255) and (Direction > 0)) 
  then Direction := - Direction // go back
  else Luminosity := Luminosity + Direction; // go forth
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Luminosity := 0;
  Direction := +1;
  Timer04.Enabled := true; 
end;
```

The variables are members of the form itself, so they exist outside of the procedure, thus can be used to keep values after the procedure exits.

---

PS. There above is a slightly noticeable delay at the ends of color swinging range (it skips one "count" by changing the sign *instead* of changing the color). If i'd did it for my projects i'd added yet extra delay (via extra counter or via tweaking timer properties) so user would really see that color stucking for a while (and giving him some time to read the text with relative comfort). That s not required by task, but it would make IMHO user experience better.

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  ....
  private 
    var
      Luminosity, Latch: byte;
      Direction:  shortint; 
    const 
      LatchInit = 5;
  end;

// Those variables exist in the form itself, outside of 
//   the procedure, thus can be used to hold the values you need.

procedure TMainForm.TimerLabelColorTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Latch > 0 then begin
     Dec(Latch);
     exit;  
  end;

  LabelSwinging.Font.Color := RGB(Luminosity, Luminosity, Luminosity);

  if ((Luminosity =   0) and (Direction < 0)) or 
     ((Luminosity = 255) and (Direction > 0)) 
  then begin 
     Direction := - Direction; // go back
     Latch := LatchInit;       // give user eyes time to relax
  end else 
     Luminosity := Luminosity + Direction; // go forth
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Luminosity := 0;  // optional: Delphi objects  anyway do zero their internal
  Latch := 0;       //    variables before entering the constructor

  Direction := +1;  // and that is required
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TimerLabelColor.Enabled := true; 
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormHide(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TimerLabelColor.Enabled := false;
end;
```

Enabling the timer has no place for it in the `OnCreate` handler for two reasons:

- What you want in `OnCreate` you can just put into DFM by changing properties in IDE's Object Inspector
- More importantly - there is little sense to change label color on invisible form, so the creation of the form is somewhat too early to start the timer sequence.

Comment: We don't need the tiemr property values and DFM text to solve this problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau hopefully so. But we better have it to be on safe side.

Answer (score 5):

Each time the timer elapses and `Timer04Timer` gets called, you are always initializing the local variables with the same color, so the resulting TLabel color is always the same.  You need to initialize the variables with the TLabel's current color instead, eg:

```
procedure TMainForm.Timer04Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  CurrentColor, RedColor, GreenColor, BlueColor: integer;
begin
  CurrentColor := ColorToRGB(Label01.Font.Color);

  RedColor := GetRValue(CurrentColor);
  GreenColor := GetGValue(CurrentColor);
  BlueColor := GetBValue(CurrentColor);

  // manipulate R, G, B as needed...

  Label01.Font.Color := RGB(RedColor, GreenColor, BlueColor);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label01.Font.Color := clBlack;
  Timer04.Enabled := true;
end;
```

Comment: There are no ref-counted variables in this code. And the local variables were being explicitly initialized: `RedColor := 1; GreenColor := 2; BlueColor := 3;`

Comment: i see. Then i misread your "You are using local variables that are always initialized" as "initialized due to being local variables". Perhaps to make wording more clear.

Comment: One more thing: you should not drop to zero but actually swig there and back. TS English is poor and i could not figure out his grayscale requirement, but then you did not got what he told of decrementing ;-)