# How to convert HSB to RGB

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I having one Delphi [XE2 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729550/how-can-you-change-the-font-color-using-timer-control) to change `Label01 Font Color` using `Timer04`. So I have written the following codes:

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer04.Enabled := true;
end;
..
..
..
..
..
procedure TMainForm.Timer04Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  StartColor, RedColor, GreenColor, BlueColor: integer;
begin
  StartColor := ColorToRGB(Label01.Font.Color);
  RedColor := GetRValue(StartColor);
  GreenColor := GetGValue(StartColor);
  BlueColor := GetBValue(StartColor);
  if RedColor <= 251 then Inc(RedColor, 1) else RedColor := 1;
  if GreenColor <= 252 then Inc(GreenColor, 2) else GreenColor := 2;
  if BlueColor <= 253 then Inc(BlueColor, 3) else BlueColor := 3;
  Label01.Font.Color := RGB(RedColor, GreenColor, BlueColor);
end;
```

This codes work perfectly. `Label01 Font Color` changes between different colors.

Now I am trying to implement that `Label02 Color` will be fixed (say Green) and the value of brightnees will be increase from **0** to **100**. If the value reaches to **100** it will be decreased to **0** and it will be continuous to a loop.

For my case I have chosen `HUE=135`, `SATURATION=85` and `BRIGHTNESS=50`. The value of `BRIGHTNESS` will be increased from **50** to **100** and then will be decreased from **100** to **0** and it will be continued.
But the problem is that there is no such `Function` available to convert `HSB` to `RGB` and vice versa in `Delphi XE2`. I have Gooled it. But I have found any `Function` as `HSBToRGB`. Only some `Delphi Unit` is availabe. I have read their revoews and found that every one is having some bugs.

Comment: What about using `ColorHLSToRGB` function from `GraphUtil.pas` unit and *convert* `TColorRef` to `TColor` ? And what ? Do not wait for me to write your code. That's what the *rent a coder* services are for. And even there I wouldn't help since I'm busy with something more important than a water effect is. And, I told you that the code which you've reposted in that previous question is fine.

Comment: You should urgently remove the part starting with @TLama

Comment: "I have read their revoews and found that every one is having some bugs." Then fix those bugs. You have the formulas - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV  - take them and apply them.

Comment: @TLama TS wants HSB aka HSV which is somewhat different from HSL

Comment: @user When I did a websearch, there were loads of hits. Try again.

Comment: @Arioch, well, so what then the `ColorHLSToRGB` function does, when it *converts colors from HLS/HBS (Hue, Lightness, Saturation/Hue, Brightness, Saturation) to RGB* ?

Comment: @TLama The point is that HLS is different from HSB. Question asks about HSB.

Comment: @TLama What can i say... Delphi help sucks again. There is no nonsense like "from HLS/HBS" at http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/graphutil/colorhlstorgb.html nor http://source.winehq.org/WineAPI/ColorHLSToRGB.html nor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773849.aspx

Comment: @Arioch, didn't know about that difference. Thanks! And I wouldn't say that only documentation is of lower quality. Using variables called `Magic1, Magic2` is somehow utter (source `ColorHLSToRGB`, Delphi XE3).

Comment: @TLama - that is not the magic. The magic in XE2 was in QC 101306 Did you expect MapReduce-like code in one of Delphi most basic routines? i still can't decide between AWful and AWesome. And Win64 assembler is still broken in XE4... To break an assembler you need to be truly stoned with magic. Okay, lets cut off the lamenting...

Comment: I guess TLama is not free as free beer and awaits for your money :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Delphi a translation of C code found here: http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html

```
function RGBFP(R, G, B: Double): TColor;
const
  RGBmax = 255;
begin
  Result := RGB(Round(RGBmax * R), Round(RGBmax * G), Round(RGBmax * B));
end;

function HSVtoRGB(H, S, V: Double): TColor;
var
  i: Integer;
  f, p, q, t: Double;
begin
  Assert(InRange(H, 0.0, 1.0));
  Assert(InRange(S, 0.0, 1.0));
  Assert(InRange(V, 0.0, 1.0));

  if S = 0.0 then
  begin
    // achromatic (grey)
    Result := RGBFP(V, V, V);
    exit;
  end;

  H := H * 6.0; // sector 0 to 5
  i := floor(H);
  f := H - i; // fractional part of H
  p := V * (1.0 - S);
  q := V * (1.0 - S * f);
  t := V * (1.0 - S * (1.0 - f));
  case i of
  0:
    Result := RGBFP(V, t, p);
  1:
    Result := RGBFP(q, V, p);
  2:
    Result := RGBFP(p, V, t);
  3:
    Result := RGBFP(p, q, V);
  4:
    Result := RGBFP(t, p, V);
  else
    Result := RGBFP(V, p, q);
  end;
end;
```

I've given this minimal testing. Please do feel free to double check it.

Comment: What unit contains the RGB function? I'm trying to use this in FireMonkey, but it doesn't recognize the RGB function.

Comment: @shaun This is a VCL question. Colors are handled differently in Firemonkey.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. Is there a unit in FireMonkey that contains an RGB function that does exactly the same thing?

Comment: @shaun Why do you want an identical function? Surely it's more important to solve the problem than to solve it in a way that uses identical code to the VCL code? Also, this is the wrong place to be asking. This is a 5 year old answer to a VCL question. You should search for FMX questions. You won't need to ask a new question because this topic is covered by documentation, blog articles and existing SO questions.

Comment: I like using default built in units for stuff instead of writing my own or importing one. I have however long since found a way to do whatever I wanted to do. I was just curious as to whether there is something like this for FMX.

Comment: Shaun Roselt - It's Winapi.Windows.pas - function RGB(r, g, b: Byte): COLORREF;
begin
  Result := (r or (g shl 8) or (b shl 16));
end; Will return BGR result (TColor).

Answer (score -1):

For Firemonkey it's **HSLtoRGB** from System.UIConsts.pas
It's similar to HSB (=HSV). All you can do with HSB you can do with HSL

```
function HSLtoRGB(H, S, L: Single): TAlphaColor;
```

It returns FMX TAlphaColor - that is RGB. 
For VCL you need TColor, that is BGR.

So use **RGBtoBGR** in the same unit.

```
function RGBtoBGR(const C: TAlphaColor): TAlphaColor;
```

Then just do 
Color := TColor(MyAlphaColorVariable);

AFAIK there is no HSB function in standard units.