# How to change HSV Value after the RGB Model to HSB Model Convertion

Tags: delphi

I am having [One `Delphi XE2` Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743821/how-to-convert-hsb-to-rgb).

I have used the following codes for RGB Model to HSB Model convertion and vice versa :

```
procedure HSVToRGB(Const H, S, V: Single; Out R, G, B: Single);
const
  SectionSize = 60/360;
var
  F: single;
  P, Q, T: single;
  Section: single;
  SectionIndex: integer;
begin
  if H < 0 then
    begin
      R:= V;
      G:= R;
      B:= R;
    end
  else
    begin
      Section:= H/SectionSize;
      SectionIndex:= Floor(Section);
      F:= Section - SectionIndex;
      P:= V * ( 1 - S );
      Q:= V * ( 1 - S * F );
      T:= V * ( 1 - S * ( 1 - F ) );
      case SectionIndex of
        0:
          begin
            R:= V;
            G:= T;
            B:= P;
          end;
        1:
          begin
            R:= Q;
            G:= V;
            B:= P;
          end;
        2:
          begin
            R:= P;
            G:= V;
            B:= T;
          end;
        3:
          begin
            R:= P;
            G:= Q;
            B:= V;
          end;
        4:
          begin
            R:= T;
            G:= P;
            B:= V;
          end;
        else
          begin
            R:= V;
            G:= P;
            B:= Q;
          end;
      end;
    end;
end;

procedure RGBToHSV(Const R, G, B: Single; Out H, S, V: Single);
var
  Range: single;
  RGB: array[0..2] of single;
  MinIndex, MaxIndex: integer;
begin
  RGB[0]:= R;
  RGB[1]:= G;
  RGB[2]:= B;

  MinIndex:= 0;
  if G < R then MinIndex:= 1;
  if B < RGB[MinIndex] then MinIndex:= 2;

  MaxIndex:= 0;
  if G > R then MaxIndex:= 1;
  if B > RGB[MaxIndex] then MaxIndex:= 2;

  Range:= RGB[MaxIndex] - RGB[MinIndex];

  if Range = 0 then
    begin
      H:= -1; 
      S:= 0; 
      V:= R; 
    end
    else
      begin
        case MaxIndex of
          0:
            begin
              H:= (G-B)/Range;
            end;
          1:
            begin
              H:= 2 + (B-R)/Range;
            end;
          2:
            begin
              H:= 4 + (R-G)/Range;
            end;
        end;
        S:= Range/RGB[MaxIndex];
        V:= RGB[MaxIndex];
        H:= H * (1/6);
        if H < 0 then H:= 1 + H;
      end;
end;
```

And also used [David Heffernan's Code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743821/how-to-convert-hsb-to-rgb/17752536#17752536) for HSV Model to RGB Model convertion.

My Requirement is to Read RGB Value of `Label02.Color`. Then Convert it to HSV Value as per `Adobe Specification` (i.e. H = 0 <-> 360, S = 0 <-> 100, V = 0 <-> 100). Then change the HSV Value. After that onlye the `V Value` will be continuously `Increased` and `Decreased` using `Timer03`.

So I also written the following codes:

```
procedure TMainForm.Timer03Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  HueOfColor, SaturationOfColor, BrightnessOfColor: single;
  RedColor, GreenColor, BlueColor: integer;
begin
  RedColor := ColorToRGB(GetRValue(Label02.Font.Color));
  GreenColor := ColorToRGB(GetGValue(Label02.Font.Color));
  BlueColor := ColorToRGB(GetBValue(Label02.Font.Color));
end;
```

I am unable to convert them using `RGBToHSV Procedure` as it is cardinal. So I am also unable to change the `V Value`. And another thing is that as per `Adobe Photoshop` the `S Value` is between `0-100` but here and in your solution also it is `0-1`. So I think I have to multiply `S Value` by 100 or divide `S Value` by 100.

Comment: If input in range 0 to 1, convert to range 0 to 100 by multiplying by 100. If input float and you need integer, use Round, but only after the multiplication. Your RGB channels are bytes in range 0..255. Divide them by 255 to get floating point in range 0..1. Why use Single?

Comment: OK. I will use `Float` instead of `Single`. But how seperate each varibles (i.e. H, S, V) from cardinal output. Please give the `Syntax`.

Comment: There is no delphi float type. Use real or double. Not that it really matters. I still don't understand your question very well.

Comment: My question is to get the value of `H, S, V` from `Label03`. First, I will read the value of RGB from `Label03`. Then I will change the value of `H, S, V`. After that I wiil convert those to RGB then I will set those changed RGB to `Label03`. I have tried `HueOfColor := GetHValue(ColorToRGB(Label03.Font.Color));`, `SaturationOfColor := GetSValue(ColorToRGB(Label03.Font.Color));` and `BrightnessOfColor := GetVValue(ColorToRGB(Label03.Font.Color));` to get those values. But it is giving error.

Comment: You seem confused about maths. You need to break it down into the bits that you don't understand. You know how to extract color channels from RGB value. You know how to convert between RGB and HSV. All that is left is converting between different scales. That's where my answer comes in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert from a floating point value x, in the range 0..N, to an integer i, in the range 0..M, do this:

```
i := Round(x*M/N);
```

In the opposite direction:

```
x := i*N/M;
```

Often one of M or N is equal to 1 which simplifies matters.

These are all the equations you will need for color space scale conversions.

Comment: I need to display the value of Hue=?, Saturation=? and Brightness=? from `ColorToRGB(Label03.Font.Color))`

Comment: You've got all the pieces here. You have RGBToHSV. And GetRValue etc. And the conversions in my answer. Now you need a clear head.

Comment: My account get banned for "Asking Question". Moderator, please remove the ban.